# Cross coupled-gm boosting stage

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, cmos

From this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6945912), a wideband differential LNA is proposed with structure below:

[image]

The first stage is called "cross coupled- gm boosting stage". I am wondering if there is a mistake here. As seen from the picture, how is it possible for transistor MN2 to be ON or in saturation here?
That connection is totally different with normal cross coupled below:

[image: Normal]

Comment: Try simulating it on LTSpice is my recommendation.

Comment: I already simulated it on Cadence and MN2 is always cut off.

Comment: Unfortunately the article is behind a paywall. I think however that you're taking the schematic a bit too literally. I guess that they just wanted to show the principle they're using. Then often some biasing sources etc. are left out ot the drawing. I suggest that you place 2 DC voltage sources in series with the gates of those 2 NM2, to lift the gate voltage so that they can conduct. 1 V DC would probably do the trick. Then check if it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Here is the paper: http://www.filedropper.com/2015awidebanddifferentiallow-noise-amplifier

Comment: Unfortunately the inner workings of the circuit are not explained in the article. But reference [2] in the article might reveal more. Or you can just google on the name of the main author of [2]. Coincidence: I know those guys from the days when I was a student :-)

Comment: If MN2 were JFETs (i.e. depletion mode) this looks plausible so I think @FakeMoustache is on to something with the DC sources.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I agree that depletion types (JFET or MOSFET) could be the answer but I'm quite sure that this is not the case here as in the sort of research it is CMOS only as that is what industry uses these days. But fortunately at least in the simulator you can fake it with a voltage source on the gate :-)

Comment: Hi, there are online version of [2] and one other. But in these cases, there are capacitive coupling. 
1. http://doc.utwente.nl/67439/1/Bru02.pdf
2. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6f40/d9ff9a6458b1c576937990cc553c90acfa0a.pdf
By the way, are you from POSTECH?